# mysql error.log centralize logs

Tags: logs, python, mysql

I'm developing a script where it will look into logs every 10 minutes and if there's any critical error it will send an e-mail to a certain adress. I have this problem i would like to solve more elegant as possible: I would like to see the logs from `/var/log/mysql/error.log` but there is several logs.

Example:

- error.log
- error.log.1.gz
- error.log.2.gz
- error.log.3.gz

From my point of view there's two way to solve this problem:
**Solution 1:**

```
try:
 open("/var/log/mysql/error.log", "rb")
except IOError:
 try:
  open("/var/log/mysql/error.log", "rb")
 except IOError:
  ....
```

You can see that this will take several `try/except` and there's probally a better way to do it. I tried to figure out something instead of several `try/except` but with no luck. Could you guys point me at the right direction? Not give me the entire answer.

**Solution 2:**

Centralize the logs into one log only. That way i would have to only open a file instead of several `try/except`. This solution seems way more elegant. I have read the `error.log` page of mysql and I didn't find any answer there to my question.

I guess a little background is necessary: it's my third day of Python and I have the basics of MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Duhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh. Every logfile from MySql is a job of logrotate. It was rotating weekly and making copies of it. The newer log was logged into `error.log` meaning that `error.log.1.gz` was something older.

Yes, i feel stupid as hell. I will leave this here if someone gets into the same trouble as i did.

Comment: Just a few angles you might be interested in: if you're worried about not checking everything since the log may have rotated away, maybe logrotate's `prerotate` option is interesting, since it lets you execute code before it rotates. (Also, maybe nagios et al. are interesting for you for system monitoring, and logwatch for daily reports.)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz i know there's a lot free software to watch logs and send an email in case of some event. I'm in my third day of python and this is a challenge to me. Would prefer to do this in python just to overcome this challenge. Thank you for your time to indicate me other angles.

Comment: No problem, and I understand wanting to fix a problem by fixing it yourself. (Sometimes it's useful to hear "hey, there's something that already addresses your problem".)